# Pandas DataFrame: keep best row combination

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, optimization, dataframe

This is my first post on StackOverflow, I'll try to be concise.

## Problem

I have 600 battery cells and need to keep 418 (as 38 groups of 11). Each cell has an internal resistance and a capacity. Cells are tested X times (salve=X).

The groups need to be formed considering these constraints:

- internal resistance ***variance*** of cells (11) inside a same group should be the ***lowest*** possible,
- total capacity  of groups (cells capacity sum) should be ***closest*** possible to each other,
- all that while keeping the best cells (best cells have ***lowest*** internal resistance and ***highest*** capacity.

But we can focus on the first constraint since it's the most important.

## Data to process

Given a file containing results from battery cells cycling:

```
salve 1:cellule 1:intRes 50:capacite 3338
salve 1:cellule 2:intRes 47:capacite 3277
...
salve 9:cellule 599:intRes 55:capacite 3267
salve 9:cellule 600:intRes 35:capacite 3487
```

I parsed all necessary data and put them in a pandas dataframe (although I am sure there is a better way to do this):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import collections

result=pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[], columns=['Salve','Cellule','InternalRes','Capacity'])

file=open('result.txt','r')

for num, line in enumerate(file):
    list=line.split(":")
    list[0]=str(list[0])[-1]
    list[1]=str(list[1])[8:]
    list[2]=str(list[2])[7:]
    list[3]=str(list[3])[9:-1]
    result.loc[num]=list
file.close()
```

I then calculated mean performance of each cell (of salve 1, salve 2, ...):

```
final=result.groupby('Cellule')['InternalRes','Capacity'].mean()
```

And kept 418 with highest capacity:

```
final=final.sort_values('Capacity', ascending=False)
final['index'] = range(1, len(final) + 1)
final = final[final['index'] < 418]
```

So this is what my dataframe looks like so far:

```
         InternalRes     Capacity  index
Cellule                                 
469        43.000000  3436.111111      1
29         45.888889  3429.555556      2
...
558        55.888889  3335.555556    416
59         42.888889  3335.333333    417
[417 rows x 3 columns]
```

I am hitting a wall now. I thought about using itertools.combinations() and numpy.var() to get best combinations, but I have great difficulties to use it with whole dataframe's row (ex: not only final['InternalRes']) to keep track of cells. Also, since this generates a lot of possibilities, processing is slow.

In a nutshell, I am trying to use .var() on each group of 'InternalRes' element of itertools.combinations and get 38 independant group (no replicated cells).Am I completely mistaken?

```
for group in itertools.combinations(final['InternalRes']):
    #calculate variance of group's InternalRes
    #keep best group
```

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847181/how-to-efficiently-sample-combinations-of-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe) slightly related to my problem.

Script efficiency isn't a big problem for now, as long as it gets the job done, but would be a +.

I am a beginner in python, please forgive me for anything dumb I've done (but I'd still like to learn from that!)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a 'var' method for 'groupby' operations. See if that can fit the bill.

Comment: @ako Yes I am sure it could be useful, the problem is that itertools.combinations() is creating tuples from data in the dataframe (and I am also loosing capacity to track which cell's resistance it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem's constraints may not be simultaneously satisfiable. It is sort of like asking for basketball teams with

- the variance of the heights as small as possible
- ages as close together as possible
- while keeping the players with the fewest turnovers and highest field-goal percentage

You need some way to *combine* the variance of the heights with the variance of
the ages with the sum of the turnovers and field-goal percentage into *a
single value*. You can then sensibly try to minimize that value.

The formula that combines the various attributes may include weights to acknowledge relative importance. The formula may be disputable, but without an objective formula, the question is unanswerable.

If we focus only on your first criteria, that

- the internal resistance variance of cells (11) inside a same group should be as low as possible

then all you need to do is **sort the rows by `InternalRes`**, and then chop the rows into 38 contiguous groups. You can't do better than this, because swapping any two values to different groups would increase the internal variance of both groups since each value would be farther from the mean of the group than it was before.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2016)
N = 600
result = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Cellule': np.arange(N),
     'InternalRes': np.random.uniform(30, 60, size=N),
     'Capacity': np.random.uniform(3000, 4000, size=N)})

final = result.groupby('Cellule')['InternalRes','Capacity'].mean()
final = final.sort_values('Capacity', ascending=False)
final = final.iloc[:418]

final = final.sort_values('InternalRes')
groups = [final.iloc[i:i+11] for i in range(0, 418, 11)]
```

---

Note that if you remove the requirement that each group have the same size, then the answer is to use [Kmeans clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). The [`scipy.vq` module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html) and [scikit-learn cluster package](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) have functions for performing kmeans clustering.

Comment: In fact, I think you are right about sort&chop the 38 groups. I didn't realise that. It sure complexify the things if we consider the other constraints, but I think that'll do for now. Many thanks!